# No deployment to [username].github.io using github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I am trying to deploy react app in the [username].github.io using github actions. Here is the workflow, i made that is build successfully but i see 404 error "no page found" in my [username].github.io site. What am i doing wrong here?

My workflow:

```
name: React CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main


jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Install Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 14
    - name: Install NPM packages
      run: npm ci
    
    - name: Build project
      run: npm run build

    - name: upload build files
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: production-files
        path: ./build
  
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    permissions:
      contents: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: production-files
        path: ./build

    - name: Deploy to gh-pages
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        publish_dir: ./build
```

If anyone could guide me on this, it would be great. I am a total beginner on CI/CD topic.

Comment: What is your repository called? What does your config look like in the Settings tab?

Comment: I got it working. I needed to save the branch from which github site was being built under settings, pages tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stupid mistake from my side. Under settings, pages tab, specify branch from which github page to be built and click save.